# Is there a general form of Chebyshev expansion coefficients for Gaussian distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, chebyshev-polynomials

$\newcommand{\chebyshevt}{\text{chebyshevt}}$
$\newcommand{\Norm}{\text{Norm}}$
I tried to calculate the coefficient for distribution $Norm(x, \mu, \sigma)$ via 
$$\int_{-1}^{1}  \chebyshevt(x, t) \Norm(x, \mu, \sigma)/\sqrt{1-x^2}dx$$
 in Wolfram but time exceeded. (t is an integral number).
But if I ignore the parameters
$$\int_{-1}^{1} \chebyshevt(x, t) \Norm(x, 0, 1)/\sqrt{1-x^2}dx$$
it is the expression including modified Bessel function of the first kind.
So I wonder if a general form exists (with (modified) Bessel function).